# Accessing gnome boxes image from outside?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, gnome

On my Fedora 25 system I use gnome boxes for some testing with debian/dnscrypt/pi-hole. Here's my problem: The image is behind NAT. I can reach it with the host system but not with other computers in my normal network.

Is it possible to change the network type to bridged for the image so that it can participate in my normal network? There aren't any network preferences in gnome boxes, but maybe there's something in a config file somewhere?